# yocto bitbake: how to know a package name from the error message and re-run it

Tags: git, yocto, bitbake

I'm running Yocto bitbake commands and I have the following error message:

> WARNING: kern-tools-native-0.2+gitAUTOINC+d6529f86fc-r12 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL git://git.yoctoproject.org/yocto-kernel-tools.git, attempting MIRRORS if available

So it seems that `git://git.yoctoproject.org/yocto-kernel-tools.git` failed.

I would like to re-run something like `bitbake -c -f fetch <package_name>` but I don't know the package name from the name of `yocto-kernel-tools.git`.

If I run: `bitbake -c -f yocto-kernel-tools`

the error message is:

> ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'yocto-kernel-tools'

Comment: bitbake uses <recipe> (not package names) so `bitbake -c fetch kern-tools-native` should do.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for "yocto-kernel-tools.git" in my meta-* folders and found that it's actually in file of `poky/meta/recipes-kernel/kenr-tools/kern-tools-native_git.bb`, so yes, as @Nayfe commented, the recipe name is `kern-tools-native`